# Is there a way to change blender default operator values?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

There are some values that I find not useful when I'm in Edit Mode and want to do, for example, a Decimate Geometry Operation. The default value is 1.00 and I would prefer to set it to .5 by default. Also, the limited dissolve operation is set to 5° by default and I would prefer to have it at 1°. This is the case for many operations but I don't know how to change the default values.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: good question...but i think, it's not possible but maybe it is a good idea to do a feature request... i would support it